# Understanding Dirac delta integrals?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

I'm confused as to how exactly to integrate using the Dirac delta function. I have the following example: $$\int \delta (x-4)(x^3-4x^2-3x+4)dx$$
and am told this evaluates to 8. Can anyone please step-by-step how to get there? I'm really struggling to understand how this integration works - I know that $\int \delta (x) =1$ but can't see how to apply this.

Comment: You just plug $4$ into the polynomial term. $\delta$ is defined by $$\int \delta(x-c)f(x)dx=f(c)$$

Comment: The result should be $-8$.

Comment: @EricAuld so then how would this work for a function like $\int \delta (-8x)(cos(x-2))dx$ ? That's my second example and apparently evaluates to $\frac{cos(-2)}8$

Comment: @Emma Change variables $u=-8x$ and then proceed as before.

Comment: In fact, I would advocate always doing a change of variables to rewrite the integral in terms of $\int \cdots \delta(u) \mathrm{d}u$. After finishing this change of variables, just evaluate the $\cdots$ at $u = 0$. This method also works in the case where you have $u = x-c$ for example.

Answer (score 3):

In general, for "nice enough" functions (and polynomials are certainly nice enough)

$$\int \delta(x) f(x) \,dx = f(0)$$

In some sense, the Dirac-$\delta$ is "infinite" at $x=0$, and $0$ everywhere else, so, if you pair it with other functions in an integral, it does a really good job of singling out the value of the function at $0$. (note that the Dirac delta is actually a distribution, so this "infinite at $0$" business is a little imprecise, but it'll be ok for now).

Similarly, if we were to apply simple translations, $\delta(x - c)$ would be "infinite" at $x = c$, so

$$\int \delta(x-c) f(x) \,dx = f(c).$$

Likewise, if we also translate $f$, we get things like

$$\int \delta(x-c_1) f(x - c_2) \,dx = f(c_1 - c_2).$$

Answer (score 3):

The idea is to evaluate the rest of the integrand at the point where the argument of $\delta$ vanishes (this only works if the argument of $\delta$ is of the form $x-c$, by the way). The argument vanishes where $x-4 = 0$, *i.e.*, at $x=4$, so evaluate the rest of the integrand at $4$.

There is a more general formula for handling the case where the argument of $\delta$ is a product of simple linear factors with no repeated roots (google it).